# Make TextBlock FIT in stack panel so I can make ellipsis

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I make `TextBlock` to resize to accomodate only available space in `StackPanel`?
`StackPanel` limited to my `Grid` layout. I just illustrated issue but in my real project it's little more complex, so ideally solution should be simple :)

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Test" />
            <TextBlock Text="Test test" />
            <Button Content="Test 2" />
            <TextBlock Width="Auto">
                Some text that I want to trim with ellipse
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper answer is to use `DockPanel` instead of `StackPanel`. Last item in DockPanel will be sized to fit remaining space which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You would better make the `StackPanel` another `Grid`:

```
<Grid> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button    Grid.Column="0" Content="Test" /> 
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Test test" /> 
        <Button    Grid.Column="2" Content="Test 2" /> 
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Some text that I want to trim with ellipse"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I changed your 'main' grid some because it looks odd having only one row and column (starting at index=0) and setting the `StackPanel` to `Grid.Row="1"` and `Grid.Column="1"`